# Shell script is downloading instead of executing

Tags: php, bash

I wrote a PHP code to execute a shell script . 
But when i execute the php script in browser , the shell script is getting downloaded , instead of executing .
Can anyone please help in resolving the issue .

Note :

PHP file source path : myuser $ /tmp/sample/index.php

index.php has the code written to execute the shell script test.sh

**index.php**

```
    <form action="test.sh" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="act" value="run">
    <input type="submit" value="run">
    </form>
```

**test.sh**

```
    #!/bin/bash

    USERNAME=sfuser
    HOSTS="pcsched01.syd.sf.priv"
    SCRIPT="touch t.txt"
    for HOSTNAME in ${HOSTS} ; do
            ssh -l ${USERNAME} ${HOSTNAME} "${SCRIPT}"
    done
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
Try like this 

<?php
    if (isset($_POST['button']))
    {
          exec("/path/to/name.sh");
    }
?>
<html>
<body>
    <form method="post">
    <p>
        <button name="button">Run Perl</button>
    </p>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: This code is executing , but not calling the shell script .

Comment: yes saravanan. i gave a correct path . may be some browser issue i guess

Answer (score 0):

You have a web server (probably Apache?) running that serves content over HTTP.
Once you submit your form, you send a request to the Web Server to serve you with the content 'test.sh' via an HTTP GET request.
The web server serves you the content.
All works as expected!

You need to create a PHP script that actually executes the SH script using, for example: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

```
<?php
exec('test.sh');
?>
```

Succes!

Comment: the exec() function is not working out . Will there be any port issue ? But did not get any error message thrown . 
Displaying the echo statement "successfully connected" but not calling the shell script . can u pls help .